# Scikit-learn models for binary classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What are the scikit-learn models available for binary classification? I tried to found in the scikit-learn.org web page an official list of that, but I didn't find.

I found these: Isolation Forest, One-Class SVM (Support Vector Machine), Elliptic Envelope, Local Outlier Factor (LOF), Minimum Covariance Determinant (MCD). But I would like to confirm, and if these compose the complete list.

Comment: We're speaking of two class or binary classification, right? One class classification is always the same class.

Comment: One way would be to search for "classifier." https://scikit-learn.org/stable/search.html?q=classifier This gets a lot of irrelevant matches, but if you scroll down to to class list starting with "AdaBoostClassifier," you will see 24 or so classifiers which can be used. Some of these, like VotingClassifier are meta-classifiers, meaning they post-process the output of another classifier somehow, so I don't know if you'd count them.

Comment: Thank you Nick ODell for the help. Yes, we are speaking of binary classification (you train the model with normal data and it can detect normal and anomalous data). I didn't understand why you consider "AdaBoostClassifier" as suitable for one-class classification, since ensemble classifiers (like AdaBoost) since are basically multiple ML algorithms separately trained used to implement a classifier. Sciki-learn has for example the One-class SVM classifier (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html), a specific SVM that they stated as suitable for one class..

Comment: 1) AdaBoostClassifier is an example of a meta-classifier, as discussed before. 2) Are you looking for a classifier which is suitable for binary classification, or a classifier which can *only* be used for binary classification? For example, GradientBoostingClassifier can be used for both binary and multiclass classification problems.

Comment: Thank you Nick ODell for the help and sorry for my delay. I am looking for classifiers suitable for binary classification (not necessarily only for binary classification).

Answer (score 1):

The well known methods are below:

1. Logistic Regression
2. Support Vector Machines (SVM)
3. Decision Trees
4. Random Forests
5. Gradient Boosting Machines
6. Neural Networks (MLPClassifier)
7. K-nearest Neighbors (KNN)
8. Naive Bayes

Note that these methods can be extended and also applied on multi-label classification problems.